# Draw UIPageControl Indicator With Core Graphics?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipagecontrol

I want to draw the following `UIPageControl` Indicator:

[image]

I currently have the following code, which results in:

[image]

```
if (isHighlighted) {
    UIBezierPath *ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 6, 6)];

    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [ovalPath stroke];
    [ovalPath addClip];

    UIColor *lightGradientColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.8 blue:0.8 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *darkGradientColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:1.0];

    CGFloat locations[2] = {0.0 ,1.0};
    CFArrayRef colors = (__bridge CFArrayRef) [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)lightGradientColor.CGColor,
               (id)darkGradientColor.CGColor,
               nil];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpc = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpc, colors, locations);

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX([ovalPath bounds]), 0), CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY([ovalPath bounds])), (CGGradientDrawingOptions)NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpc);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
} else {
    UIBezierPath *ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 6, 6)];
    [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.3] setFill];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [ovalPath fill];
}
```

But I can't get it to look like the indicator in the picture. How would I manage to get the right result?

Comment: If outcommneted code isn't relevant; don't include it.

Comment: Sorry, the edit system accidentally readded the removed outcommented code, so I had to re-edit it again. Seems like it's finally fixed.

Comment: Post another image of what your current implementation looks like. It's hard to discern from the code alone what the result of your drawing will be.

Comment: Okay... Image of the current result added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you're trying to replicate is *really* tiny. You might find it easier to dissect if you look at a large version -- set your simulator to Retina mode, or take a screenshot on a Retina device, and blow that up. (Maybe post that here, too?) Also, don't think code first -- think about what you're drawing, then worry about the code to do it.

What it looks to me like you've got: Both dots might be built with three concentric circles, of radius 2, 3, and 4 pt. For the white one: draw the 4-pt-radius circle first in a dark gray (or semi-transparent black) fill. Then on top of that, a 3-pt-radius circle with a light-to-medium gray gradient fill (oriented vertically, not diagonally like you have). Finally, draw the inner 2-pt-radius circle with no fill and a 1pt gradient (lighter-to-light gray) stroke. Take a close look at the dark circle and you can probably come up with a similar strategy for drawing that.